# Error in LaTeX output of doxygen documentation of VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, doxygen

I try to produce Latex documentation for my VHDL project.
It is alright for the most part except there are "Namespace Documentation" instead of "Package Documentation" and "Class Documentation" instead of "Entity Documentation".

I turned on optimize for VHDL.

Is it a bug or I am doing something wrong?

Edit: output of doxygen -x

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.8.16 (cfd73d5c4d1a66c620a3b7c08b72a3f3c3f94
255*)
PROJECT_NAME           = "2D DFT and Filtering"
PROJECT_BRIEF          = "VHDL implementation of 2D DFT and Filtering"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = vhdl
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = YES
INPUT                  = ../Vivado/Processing_System/Processing_System.srcs/sources_1/new
EXCLUDE                = ../Vivado/Processing_System/Processing_System.srcs/sources_1/new/twiddle_factor_15x15.vhd
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
```

Comment: here is config file https://pastebin.com/Yp2yXtqb

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? please also add a small example to the question that shows the problem and also add the differences of the configuration file in respect to the default configuration file (doxygen 1.8.15 and up: `doxygen -x`).

Comment: @albert added the doxygen -x. Since the problem is with category names any package and entity shoud do it

Comment: I recognize the directory names as the same as for a doxygen issue, and I did a quick test and see indeed here the non-translated names. Sounds a bit like overkill but due to time limitations it is better to have an issue to prevent that the problem gets lost so please file an issue (same case as for the other issue will do).